# "lead to" and "lead something/somebody to"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning

I am curious that the difference between **lead to** and **lead something/somebody to**.

I know the verb *lead* can be used both intransitive and transitive way.

What I want to know is that **lead to**, which is synonymous to *cause*, *give rise to* has same meaning with **lead something to**.

Does **lead something to** have the same meaning with **cause** and **result in**?

Answer (score 0):

*X lead(s) to Z* means if you follow X, you will get to Y.

*X lead(s) Y to Z* means Y is following X, and X and Y will get to Z.

Both can be used to talk about results or causes.

> This leads to disaster.
>
> This will lead your friend to disaster.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, `I am curious about the difference`,

**not** `I am curious that the difference`.

Yes, you can use the verb "lead" as either an intransitive verb or a transitive verb.

Are they the same meaning? It depends on the context. They can be almost the same meaning in a similar context.

> Stress can lead you to do bad things.

"*You*" is a direct object and "*to do bad things*" is an object complement. However, both of them are connected to the verb "*lead*".

or

> Stress can lead to doing bad things

"To" is a preposition, so after it, you need to use a noun/noun phrase or verb+ing form.

or

> Stress can lead to bad things.

They all are the same meaning.

Comment: I don't agree that they have the same meaning. *Doing* bad things means that there is an agent of the bad things. Whereas without *doing*, things could simply occur. For example, if I'm stressed I could *do* bad things by snapping at people and making bad decisions. However, stress could also cause me to break out in a rash—without any action on my part at all..